# Excel VBA For each cell in range seems to run through the same cell multiple number of times

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, range, cell

The "for-each cell in range" statement seems to be running through the same cell multiple number of times.

See the screenshot.

It runs through the cell that has the word "Product" four time, because it is merged across four rows.

Is there a way to make it run only once, regardless of the design of the worksheet (in other words, I prefer not to use the fact that it is merged across four rows to be taken into account when coding).

[image: EXCEL]

```
Public Sub ProcessBeijingFile(Excel_UNC_Path As String)

    Dim src As Workbook

    Dim ProdPushWorkbook As Workbook

    Set ProdPushWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook


    Set src = Workbooks.Open(Excel_UNC_Path, True, True)

    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim text As String

    src.Sheets("Page 1").Activate

    src.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    LastRow = src.ActiveSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row
    text = LastRow
    text = "A2:BA" + CStr(text)

    Set r = Range(text)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To MaxItems
        PONumber(i) = ""
    Next


    Dim PageCounter As Integer
    PageCounter = 0
    RecordCounter = 0

    Dim NextPONumber As String
    NextPONumber = ""


    For Each c In r



        If Left(Trim(c.Value), 5) = "PO No" Then
            NextPONumber = Trim(Replace(c.Value, "PO No.:", ""))
            NextPONumber = Trim(Replace(NextPONumber, "PO No:", ""))
        End If
            ....
```

Comment: What is the problem with this? There is no performance hit and you don't care what is in the merged cell.

Comment: You can add a check to see whether it’s a merged cell and tell it to skip a cell if it’s not the first cell in that merge

Comment: You could probably do something with the `Range.MergeCells` and/or `Range.MergeArea` properties to check if the cell is in a merged area, and only process it if it's the top-left cell within the merged area.

Comment: Good idea David wish I’d thought of it :P

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance and just want simple code, below demonstrates how you can go about skipping MergedCells. It displays address and value of non empty cells from Cell B1 in Immediate window until it reach empty cell. Kind of what you need.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oRng = Range("B1")
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng)
        Debug.Print oRng.Address, oRng.Value
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1)
    Loop
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

David pointed me in the right direction.
Here is the key:

```
if c.MergeCells then
      If Trim(GetFirstWord(c.MergeArea.Address, ":")) = c.Address Then
            'the first of merged cells, then process, else don't process...
```

Function Needed:

```
Public Function GetFirstWord(ByVal SearchString As String, Optional ByVal Delimeter As String = " ") As String



    If SearchString = "" Then
        GetFirstWord = ""
Else

    Dim ary As Variant
    ary = Split(SearchString, Delimeter)
    GetFirstWord = ary(LBound(ary))
End If


'    GetFirstWord = ary(LBound(ary))
'GetFirstWord = ary(LBound(ary))
```

End Function